# CloudKit - recordZoneFetchCompletionBlock shows 1000's of deleted records

Tags: sql-delete, cloudkit

I noticed something strange during testing. First, I `Erase All Content and Settings` on the simulator, and then manually delete all records in `CloudKit`. When I first run the app, I've noticed that over 2000 records are being deleted. I don't understand why (or even where!) they are being stored. Have I completely missed something? Below is a portion of the CloudKit method that is run as part of a check for updates.

```
operation.fetchDatabaseChangesCompletionBlock = { (token, more, error) in
    if error != nil {
        finishClosure(UIBackgroundFetchResult.failed)
    } else if !zonesIDs.isEmpty {
        changeToken = token
        let configuration = CKFetchRecordZoneChangesOperation.ZoneConfiguration()
        configuration.previousServerChangeToken = changeZoneToken

        let fetchOperation = CKFetchRecordZoneChangesOperation(recordZoneIDs: zonesIDs, configurationsByRecordZoneID: [zonesIDs[0]: configuration])

        fetchOperation.recordChangedBlock = { (record) in
            listRecordsUpdated.append(record)
        }

        fetchOperation.recordWithIDWasDeletedBlock = { (recordID, recordType) in
            if changeToken != nil {
                listRecordsDeleted[recordID.recordName] = recordType
            }
         }

         fetchOperation.recordZoneChangeTokensUpdatedBlock = { (zoneID, token, data) in
             changeZoneToken = token
         }

         fetchOperation.recordZoneFetchCompletionBlock = { (zoneID, token, data, more, error) in
             if error != nil {
                 print("Error")
             } else {
                 changeZoneToken = token
                 self.updateLocalRecords(listRecordsUpdated: listRecordsUpdated)
                 self.deleteLocalRecords(listRecordsDeleted: listRecordsDeleted)
                 listRecordsUpdated.removeAll()
                 listRecordsDeleted.removeAll()
             }
         }
etc.
```

**Delete Records**

```
func deleteLocalRecords(listRecordsDeleted: [String : String]) {
   for (recordName, recordType) in listRecordsDeleted {
      let request: NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult> = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "\(recordType)")
      request.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "ckrecordname = %@", recordName)
       do {
          let result = try context.fetch(request)
          if !result.isEmpty {
             if let data = result[0] as? NSManagedObject {
                context.delete(data)
              }
            }
         }
         catch {
             print("Error fetching")
         }
    }
    coreData.saveContext()
}
```

Comment: It sounds like you're deleting the records through the dashboard but are keeping the record zone correct? In that case the deletes are part of the history of the zone, and when you first sync with the zone it basically rewinds through all that history for the zone, which at the end includes deletes for all your records.  Does the number of records deleted make sense in that context, or is the number not reflecting the actual number of records you've deleted in the zone since creation?  What happens when you reset the development environment?

Comment: Your explanation makes perfect sense, thank you! I have deleted a LOT of records during testing.  As for resetting the environment, that button is bright red so I've been avoiding it. But it sounds like deleting the custom zone may fix this issue. And perhaps CloudKit will even recreate it the next time I run the app? If you'd like to put your comment above in the form of an answer I will happily accept it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you're deleting the records through the dashboard but are keeping the record zone. In that case the deletes are part of the history of the zone, and when you first sync with the zone it basically rewinds through all that history for the zone, which at the end includes deletes for all your records.

Keep in mind this also applies to zones - so a zone delete for example stays in the history and can lead to some unwanted situations if you don't account for that. I ran into the situation where I was deleting the zone on one device, but the other one would then try to sync, find no zone and create it again.